# Copy and paste based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a script in a workbook that will check a separate worksheet ("Worksheet 2") in row 10 for a value ("Yes") - See
[Worksheet 2 Column B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wH93.jpg)

If it returns with a yes I want to copy the cell in Row 4 in the same column (in this case B4) and paste it to "Worksheet 1" in column B starting on Row 2 - See [Worksheet 1 Column B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkBJD.jpg)

Then I want it to check the next 100 rows for the same info and paste all of the Row 4 Cells that have yes from Row 10 into "Worksheet 1 - Row B".  Here is what I currently have:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For Each Sheets("Option 2").Cell In Range("B10:CZ10")
        If Cell.Value = Range("Yes").Value Then
       Worksheets("Option 2").Cell.Range(B4).Copy Range("B")
       Exit Sub
    End If
Next Cell
    Worksheets("Option 2").Range("B5:CW10").Copy Range("B")
    Range("B" & lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Sorry if this is written horribly.  I'm new to VBA and don't have a lot of guidance.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you mean look at 100 columns, row 10 in Option2 and for each that say yes, copy those row 4 cells in those columns and paste them to the next available row worksheet 1 starting column B? If so, you could just use an If statement. And if yes, would you want spaces between the values in sheet 1 or all next to each other?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Correct, I want it to look at all 100 columns, row 10 in Option 2.  When it lists the returned data from Row 4 cell, I'd like it to list it row by row in Column B on Worksheet 1.  No need to skip a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are attempting.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lr As Long, rng as range

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rng In Sheets("Option 2").Range("B10:CZ10")
        If lcase(rng.Value) = "yes" Then
            lr = lr+1
            cells(lr, "B") = rng.offset(-6, 0).value
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Good news is I'm not getting an error, but the data isn't populating onto Worksheet 1.  I set the command button on worksheet 1, is that the problem?

Comment: Step through it with F8 and keep a watch on the lr variable. Yes, the code should be non the Sheet1 (destination) code sheet.

Comment: thanks!  I got it to work by removing "lcase".  Not sure why it worked, but it worked!!

Comment: Sounds like you changed my "yes" to "Yes". The lcase(rng.Value) = "yes" was intended to make the comparison case insensitive.